# Excel: adding value if the other cell contains certain value

Tags: excel

here is [the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQDxd.png) which is pretty self explaining.
I need excel to run through each row in **A** column and if it's 'volvo' (in this case) i need it to add the value next to it.
 The sum of values should be in the cell below (A5).
The poor solution which I came up with and does not work is
 `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("volvo";A1:A3));B1:B3;0))`
Thank you for every reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMIFS()

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"volvo")
```